# Jmeter how to generate hash sha512

Tags: java, jmeter, sha512, jsr223

I need to create test in jmeter for many requests and I need to create post request which will contain `pass` in header and it should be hash sha512 from `user + someid + someid`. I need to change user in each request so I just add in Header Manager `user${__threadNum}`, it looks fine but I need to generate hash from this in next post request. I was searching that it should be possible via beanshell script or jsr223 preprocessor, but I am not very familiar with scripting or java.

Comment: You could use a BeanShell to get the hash via a Bash command, something like `echo -n "test" | openssl sha512`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Since JMeter 4.0, the easier answer is:**

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/49805027/460802

**For previous versions :**

Add [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) with Java language, pass variables password and salt using  `vars.get("password")` and using this code variable `generatedPassword` will hold the new hash generated

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

String passwordToHash = vars.get("password");
String   salt= vars.get("salt");
String generatedPassword = null;
    try {
     MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
     md.update(salt.getBytes("UTF-8"));
     byte[] bytes = md.digest(passwordToHash.getBytes("UTF-8"));
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     for(int i=0; i< bytes.length ;i++){
        sb.append(Integer.toString((bytes[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
     }
     generatedPassword = sb.toString();
     log.info(generatedPassword);
     vars.put("generatedPassword", generatedPassword);
    } 
   catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Comment: thanks, but I am still a bit confused... where should I put `vars.get("password")` to parameters in JSR223 PreProcessor? And in User Parameters define password as ${user}${someid}${someid} or how? Than can I use ${generatedPassword}?

Comment: Define as JMeter variable `password` for example in `User Parameters` with value as `${user}${someid}${someid}` and in the end, Yes, use ${generatedPassword}

Comment: I tried this but in response I still can se only this and not hash
`user1: ${generatedPassword}`

Comment: Add your test plan to question maybe your order is wrong or check also jmeter.log if any error occurred

Comment: in User Parameters I have 
`user: user123
someid: id123
someid2: id12345
password: ${user}${someid}${someid2}`

in JSR223 PreProcessor I have mentioned code and than I have Header Manager with header 
user${__threadNum}: ${generatedPassword}

but in request I see in Requests Headers only user1: ${generatedPassword}. Is it correct settings? I will check log, or change order...

Comment: ok so problem was that salt was not defined, now it is working fine. Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

Using JMeter >= 4.0, just use function [__digest](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__digest):

> ${__digest(SHA-512,string to hash,,,)}

Comment: This seems to want to set a property on the script file. How do you get the output?

Comment: No such property: a600410b157b2648e5be914bfe7f1466c4249b2d63b227861209b6a68d75274e for class: Script60